# Unity3d Android, app crashes when focus back from browser using back button

Tags: android, crash, unity-game-engine, accessibility, back-button

I am using Unity3d Version 4.3.  My game is crashing when focus back from web browser by 'multiple fast' tapping back button.

When focus out, it closes web socket, and when come back it opens again. That's all.

It doesn't happen when slowly touch twice. The screen animated and comes back safely.

The log cat says.

**" Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: accessibility_enabled "**

Comment: What else the `LogCat` says? Also some relevant code would help.

Comment: Actually, it works find in iOS. So, there is little to comment.

Comment: It just re-connect game server, open web socket. When I touch back button twice, it's fine. So, the source code doesn't seem to have problems.